# How to update an Android app by only sending the code that changed instead of the whole bundle for each update?

Tags: android

I have an android app which incorporates a jar file which is 6mb  in size. I want to be able to provide updates to my app without bundling the 6mb jar for each update, instead only send the application code that changed for each update. Someone please let me know if this is possible?

Comment: As far as I know, Google play store does exactly this. While you upload the full package, the play store sends only deltas to the devices. (see http://www.engadget.com/2012/08/16/google-play-store-delta-updates/)

Answer (score 0):

Not through the play store.  I doubt it would be possible outside it either-  Android apks are signed.  I'm not sure if the signature would work after diffing.

Really though, why do you care?  If its through the play store, 6 MB isn't much to download.  It'll just take a few seconds.  If you're handing out the apk, then it won't even take that.  It seems like it really isn't worth worrying about.

Comment: Thanks all the thoughtful responses. My requirement is for a scenario where my app users are on a low bandwidth network, so that is the reason 6mb is huge. What @Henry has posted about the Google Play's ability to send the delta would be exactly what I am looking for. Thanks again for the quick and thoughtful response.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this depends. If you can be smart about it you can probably do it for some apps. For example if you need to update images and data, you might put a data-package in your app that you can download from a web server you set up your self. Problem is that you need to put some thought into it and it does not work for all kinds of apps.

Answer (score 0):

6mb really is no big deal. I would use PlayStore for updates. My apps are 22mb and I stil use it.

If you're really concerned, you can either put the large content that makes your app up like Images on the internet and then design your app to download them on startup if they don't exist. So this way, it will remain on the SD even though app is updated.